# php fpm pools error_log are being written to global error log file

Tags: php

We're having a problem when all php error logs are being written to global log: /var/log/php-fpm/error.log instead of individual pool logs.
Is there a way to fix this?

Global config:

```
[root@linuxbox88 etc]# grep error php-fpm.conf
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

www.conf

```
[root@linuxbox88 php-fpm.d]# grep error_log www.conf
;       (error_log, sessions.save_path, ...).
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

error.log

```
[20-Aug-2018 18:59:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 19103 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'dawiu' (T_STRING) in /usr/share/nginx/public_html/test.php on line 1"
[20-Aug-2018 19:00:04] WARNING: [pool www] child 19105 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'dawiu' (T_STRING) in /usr/share/nginx/public_html/test.php on line 1"
[20-Aug-2018 19:00:05] WARNING: [pool www] child 19101 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'dawiu' (T_STRING) in /usr/share/nginx/public_html/test.php on line 1"
[20-Aug-2018 19:00:05] WARNING: [pool www] child 19097 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'dawiu' (T_STRING) in /usr/share/nginx/public_html/test.php on line 1"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php) function. With this function you can adjust a lot of parameters for a custom logging so that it fits your needs.